# iphone use Quart2D api in drawRect have 1px redundant line？

Tags: ios, iphone, drawrect

I use Quart2D to draw rects but not work as I think.

My code as below:

```
-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.2]setFill];
CGRect grayRect = self.frame;
UIRectFill(grayRect);

CGRect cropRect = _intersectionRect;
CGRect intersectionRect = CGRectIntersection(cropRect, grayRect);
[[UIColor clearColor]setFill];
UIRectFill(intersectionRect);
}
```

In a blank project to run a demo, everything works fine:

[image]

But in may project, I get 1 px line with different alpha value:

[image]

It takes me hours to debug.. I will be appreciate to who give me an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved.

The two rect's value should be **int rather then float**.